# Make text fit inside a column rounded div

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm using Bootstrap 5 and dividing a row with two columns next to each other. I'd like to use rounded borders for the left one but I need the content to stay inside the div.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 rounded-pill border encabezado-clinica">
            <div class="col-md-12 p-2">
                <h2>{{clinic.name}}</h2>
                <h5><img src="{% static 'img/icons/hospital.svg' %}">{{clinic.get_speciality_display}}</h5>
                <h5><img src="{% static 'img/icons/geo-alt.svg' %}">{{clinic.full_address}}</h5>
                <h5><img src="{% static 'img/icons/train-front.svg' %}">{{clinic.train_access}}</h5>
                <h5><img src="{% static 'img/icons/bus-front.svg' %}">{{clinic.bus_access}}</h5>
                <h5><img src="{% static 'img/icons/p-square.svg' %}">{{clinic.parking}}</h5>
                <h5><img src="{% static 'img/icons/telephone.svg' %}">{{clinic.phone_number}}</h5>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And custom class css at the moment:

```
.encabezado-clinica {
    shape-outside: margin-box;
}
```

[Here is the result now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hbtmt.png)

I tried changing the `overflow` and `shape-outside` css properties without exit. I would need the rendered text to stay inside the div and then be able to adjust padding. Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here your html code with little modification.

```
<div class="row mx-0">
      <div class="col-6 encabezado-clinica">
        <div class="py-5">
          <h2>{{clinic.name}}</h2>
          <h5>
            <img
              src="{% static 'img/icons/hospital.svg' %}"
            />{{clinic.get_speciality_display}}
          </h5>
          <h5>
            <img
              src="{% static 'img/icons/geo-alt.svg' %}"
            />{{clinic.full_address}}
          </h5>
          <h5>
            <img
              src="{% static 'img/icons/train-front.svg' %}"
            />{{clinic.train_access}}
          </h5>
          <h5>
            <img
              src="{% static 'img/icons/bus-front.svg' %}"
            />{{clinic.bus_access}}
          </h5>
          <h5>
            <img
              src="{% static 'img/icons/p-square.svg' %}"
            />{{clinic.parking}}
          </h5>
          <h5>
            <img
              src="{% static 'img/icons/telephone.svg' %}"
            />{{clinic.phone_number}}
          </h5>
        </div>
      </div>
 </div>
```

just write your css like this

```
.encabezado-clinica {
        border: 1px solid gray;
        border-radius: 50%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You must add to radius container: `text-align: center; min-width: max-content; padding: 20px 0;`.

Try it:

```css
.encabezado-clinica {
  shape-outside: margin-box;
}
.rounded-pill{
  border-radius: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: max-content;
  padding: 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6 rounded-pill border encabezado-clinica">
    <div class="col-md-12 p-2">
      <h2>{{clinic.name}}</h2>
      <h5><img src="{% static 'img/icons/hospital.svg' %}">{{clinic.get_speciality_display}}</h5>
      <h5><img src="{% static 'img/icons/geo-alt.svg' %}">{{clinic.full_address}}</h5>
      <h5><img src="{% static 'img/icons/train-front.svg' %}">{{clinic.train_access}}</h5>
      <h5><img src="{% static 'img/icons/bus-front.svg' %}">{{clinic.bus_access}}</h5>
      <h5><img src="{% static 'img/icons/p-square.svg' %}">{{clinic.parking}}</h5>
      <h5><img src="{% static 'img/icons/telephone.svg' %}">{{clinic.phone_number}}</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```